# How can I update my materials to work with LWRP?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, materials

I'm using Unity 2019.1.6f1.

When I open a new scene with  the LWRP template project, I see errors from all materials in the scene. For example, the Jigsaw appears in my scene but in console window I see a message telling me:

> Jigsaw_Mat material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert Lightweight Render Pipeline/Lit shader to selected pipeline
>   UnityEditor.Rendering.LWRP.LightweightRenderPipelineMaterialUpgrader:UpgradeProjectMaterials()

[image: Screenshot of material experiencing error]

All materials show this message, and I don't know what to do to fix these materials. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upgrade all the materials that can be supported by LWRP, go to:

Edit Menu -> Render Pipeline -> Lightweight Render Pipeline -> Update Project Materials to LightweightRP Materials

Note - only standard shader materials will be brought across. Lit/specialist shaders will not be converted automatically. You will see warnings in the console about those the cannot be imported.

**FBX meshes with embedded materials**

If you have any FBX imported objects, you will need to reimport them. The easiest way to do them is to find your FBX models in the Project window, right click the FBX and choose Reimport.

Don't forget to save once you've done that!

Tested in Unity 2019.2.0f1.